# text input field pushing fixed-width sibling element out of flex parent

Tags: html, css, forms, flexbox

I have a problem; I have a div with `display: flex;` which has two children horizontally. The first (the `<input>`) has to fill the remaining space, while the second (the `<button>`) has a specific width and height (40x40px).

The problem is that the input is getting 100% of the space, pushing the button out of the div. This div with flex is also in another div (the container); because I need the whole page width to be only 30%, maybe that is the problem but I don't know.

```css
.container {
  margin: auto;
  padding: 1rem;
  width: 30%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.row input {
  flex: 1 /* I tried flex:1 and flex-grow: 1 but with or without it I stays the same */
}

.row button {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <form action='' method='post'>

    <div class='row'>
      <input type='text' name=''>
      <button>some icon</button>
    </div>

  </form>
</div>
```

As above I tried using `flex: 1;` and `flex-grow: 1;` but nothing changes. I want to make content of `.row` not getting out div's width as it is right now. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is the missing `size` attribute of the text input element, which causes a default size (20) that's too large for small/narrow screens in your particular situation. If you add `size="4"` or even smaller as an attribute to the input (in HTML, no in CSS), it will work as intended:

```css
.container {
  margin: auto;
  padding: 1rem;
  width: 30%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.row input {
  flex: 1;
}

.row button {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <form action='' method='post'>

    <div class='row'>
      <input type='text' name='' size="4">
      <button>some icon</button>
    </div>

  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, I will try it tomorrow in my project but as I see in code snippet it works just as I wanted to. Thank you very much :D

Comment: edit: I tried it and it really works, thanks!